# How do I shift the hue of a LWJGL texture?

Tags: opengl, colors

I am trying to do a Photoshop-like hue shift on a texture.

My code is somewhat like this:

```
glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
//bind texture, draw quad, etc.
```

Here is a picture describing what happens:
[I can't post images yet, so here's a link.](http://oi40.tinypic.com/xgfqsk.jpg)

Comment: The linked picture seems to be no longer available, so it is difficult to know what this question is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change hue of a texture with GLSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234724/how-to-change-hue-of-a-texture-with-glsl)