# Color Space Conversion ( ARGB -> YUV420 ) Using OpenGL Shaders

Tags: opengl, graphics, opengl-es-2.0, shader, color-space

Is it possible to Convert an ARGB Image to YUV420 ( planar or semiplanar ) Image using openGL Frament Shaders?

I am Looking for a Fragment Shader code  or any referenece guide which will help me to Achieve this?

I Referred [RGB to YUV using GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264532/rgb-to-yuv-using-glsl).
But it wasnt much informative.

I need the YUV420 image to pass it to the h264 Encoder.
Any Working or Reference Shader Code?

Comment: Please post your code and describe what doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV):

> Weighted values of R, G, and B are summed to produce Y', a measure of
>   overall brightness or luminance. U and V are computed as scaled
>   differences between Y' and the B and R values.

So, you can make a constant 3x3 matrix in your shader, such as:

[image]

That matrix would be valid if you use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) standard. So, sample your original texture, multiply it by that matrix, and bake the results in a FBO. It's a pretty straightforward process.

Hope that is enough information. Feel free to comment if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for Info Dim, I will follow this approach and let you know.
I am new to GLSL so looking for some reference code. :)

Comment: All that I can refer you to right now, are [these tutorials](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/?texture). I am unaware whether you've already created and compiled your first shaders, or if you're just planning to start, so check these tutorials. All the information you require is there. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dimo Markov who already explained how to do the color space transformation, in case of performing chroma subsampling you also have to reduce the resolution of the color planes.

To implement this, you'd use three passes, one each for Y, U and V. Instead of a matrix-vector multiplication things would boil down to a simple inner (= dot) product. The subsampling itself is achieved by rendering to a smaller render buffer and relying on the source texture mipmap filtering.