# How to Edit a Texture Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, textures

I am making a game in which I would like users to be able to customize their characters. I do not want to have a set of different textures for each color, because as the customization gets more complex there might be thousands of combinations.

**My goal is to programmatically set the color of a array of pixels in an image and save it for later use within the game.**

There seems to be very little documentation on editing images programmatically beyond applying simple effects and cropping, so any help is appreciated.

**Edit One:**

This app is still conceptual. I posted this question to get an idea of how to achieve the goal detailed above.  I will probably be using openGL ES for this app.

Comment: You need to be more clear about how you're doing your drawing. Are you using OpenGL? Core Graphics? SpriteKit? Something else? Without more specific information, nobody can help you.

Comment: @user1118321 I really don't think it matters how I am displaying an image when I only need to edit it and overwrite it.

Comment: It absolutely matters. There are very different techniques for editing the images and overwriting them. In OpenGL you'd use a shader. In CoreGraphics, you can use CoreImage filters. SpriteKit would probably be something else. We can't tell you what to do unless we know what you've already got.

Comment: Is your texture in an array? Why can't you just make a copy of your array and then change the value of each pixel?

Comment: @user1118321: I've edited my post about how I am displaying the image

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer: No, my texture is not in an array, I used that term to indicate that a had...a set of pixels to change.

Comment: [Here's a shader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234724/how-to-change-hue-of-a-texture-with-glsl/9234854#9234854) that will allow you to change the hue of a texture in OpenGL.

Comment: How are you storing the texture then?